# How to run Functions from time to time, without stopping others?

Tags: python, process

I have this program that writes an xml and write some other files, but there`s a thing that I want to do and I don`t know how, I have a function that checks if some files are in the startup folder, and other functions that run every minute, I want to make the function to check if files are there from 30 to 30 minutes, without stopping the other functions to run minute by minute, how can I do that?

```
#this one needs to run from 30 to 30 minutes     


def modifica_xml(self):

    global xmlformatado
    self.IV_config.read('config.ini')
    MakerStudio = self.IV_config['config']['MakerStudio'] + '\sntlconfig.xml'
    print(MakerStudio)
    Boostrap = self.IV_config['config']['Bootstrap'] + '\sntlconfig.xml'

    print(Boostrap)

    xmlconfig = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>
                        <SentinelConfiguration><SentinelKeys><Protocol>SP_TCP_PROTOCOL
                        </Protocol><ContactServer>{}</ContactServer><Heartbeat>60</Heartbeat>
                        </SentinelKeys></SentinelConfiguration>'''
    try:
        xmlformatado = xmlconfig.format(self.IV_linksFuncionando[0])
    except IndexError:
        pass

    if os.path.exists(self.IV_arquivotxt):
        self.IV_autodestruct = len(open(self.IV_arquivotxt).readlines())
        if self.IV_autodestruct >= 180:
            os.remove(self.IV_arquivotxt)
            print("Arquivo excluido apos 3 horas")
    else:
        pass
    try:
        print('Utilizando ' + self.IV_linksFuncionando[0])
        with open(Boostrap, 'w') as f:
            f.write(xmlconfig.format(self.IV_linksFuncionando[0]))
            f.close()
    except IndexError:
        print("Ambos servidores estao offline")
    except PermissionError:
        pass
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass

    try:
        print('Utilizando ' + self.IV_linksFuncionando[0])
        with open(MakerStudio, 'w') as f:
            f.write(xmlconfig.format(self.IV_linksFuncionando[0]))
            f.close()
    except IndexError:
        print("Ambos servidores estao offline")
    except PermissionError:
        pass
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
```

## This one needs to run every minute

```
def escreve_txt(self):
    try:
        with open(self.IV_arquivotxt, 'a') as x:
            x.write('Licença em uso ' + str(self.IV_linksFuncionando[0]) + '  ' + str(datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S")) + '\n')
            x.close()
    except IndexError:
        with open(self.IV_arquivotxt, 'a') as x:
            x.write('Ambos servidores offline ' + str(datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S")))
            x.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set a timestamp for the next time the function should be called:

```
import time

next_1min = 0
next_30min = 0
while True:
    ts = time.time()
    if ts > next_1min:
        next_1min = ts + 60
        your_1min_f()

    if ts > next_30min:
        next_30min = ts + 30*60
        your_30min_f()
```

and if you want the functions to run at fixed intervals (say 9h30, 10h00, 10h30...)
you can set the increment to:

```
next_30min = ts - ts % (30*60) + 30*60
```

and in case you need to call the functions exactly at the same time then you have to use some kind of parallelism, for example using the threading module:

```
import time
import threading

next_1min = 0
next_30min = 0
while True:
    ts = time.time()
    if ts > next_1min:
        next_1min = ts - ts % 60 + 60
        threading.Thread(target= your_1min_f).start()

    if ts > next_30min:
        next_30min = ts - ts % (30*60) + 30*60
        threading.Thread(target= your_30min_f).start()
```